# The sign # not display on call screen Android

Tags: android, call

I created an app to call to number `*123456789#`, but when the app calls this number, Android just calls `*123456789` (without the `#`).

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to post up your code for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to encode the phone number.

```
String phonenumber = "*123456789#"; 
encodedPhonenumber = URLEncoder.encode(phonenumber, "UTF-8");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedPhonenumber)));
```

Comment: I test susccessful.
Thank for your support!